# How to fetch nested object of OneToMany?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

I need to fetch nested `address` objects for customers collection:

```
Ebean.find(Company.class)  
        .fetch("customers") 
        .fetch("customers.address") 
        .findList();
```

But it fetches only list of `customer`'s and `customer.address.id` field, other fields in `address` object are `null`. Hot to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the most obvious way:

```
.fetch("customers.address.fieldOne")
.fetch("customers.address.fieldTwo")
```